# UI-Router - Change $state without rerender/reload of the page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been looking at these pages ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585065/angularjs-ui-router-change-url-without-reloading-state), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121695/change-url-of-angular-ui-router-without-reloading-page), [3](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/64)). I basically want to change my `$state`, but I don't want the page to reload.

I am currently in the page `/schedules/2/4/2014`, and I want to go into edit mode when I click a button and have the URL become `/schedules/2/4/2014/edit`.

My `edit` state is simply `$scope.isEdit = true`, so there is no point of reloading the whole page. However, I do want the `$state` and/or `url` to change so that if the user refreshses the page, it starts in the edit mode.

What can I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For this problem, you can just create a child state that has neither `templateUrl` nor `controller`, and advance between `states` normally:

```
// UPDATED
$stateProvider
    .state('schedules', {
        url: "/schedules/:day/:month/:year",
        templateUrl: 'schedules.html',
        abstract: true, // make this abstract
        controller: function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
            $scope.schedDate = moment($stateParams.year + '-' + 
                                      $stateParams.month + '-' + 
                                      $stateParams.day);
            $scope.isEdit = false;

            $scope.gotoEdit = function() {
                $scope.isEdit = true;
                $state.go('schedules.edit');
            };

            $scope.gotoView = function() {
                $scope.isEdit = false;
                $state.go('schedules.view');
            };
        },
        resolve: {...}
    })
    .state('schedules.view', { // added view mode
        url: "/view"
    })
    .state('schedules.edit', { // both children share controller above
        url: "/edit"
    });
```

An important [concept](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#nested-states--views) here is that, in `ui-router`, when the application is in a particular state—when a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.

So, in this case,

- when your application advances from view mode to edit mode, its parent state `schedules` (along with its `templateUrl`, `controller` and even `resolve`) will still be retained.
- since ancestor states are implicitly activated, even if the child state is being refreshed (or loaded directly from a bookmark), the page will still render correctly.

Comment: This would work, except that I already have an abstract state `schedule`, and then two children of it: `schedule.view`, and `schedule.edit`. I need this hierarchy. What you are suggesting would then mean I need to have `schedule`, `schedule.view`, and `schedule.view.edit` which (for reasons I that will take a while), I cannot have

Comment: @Kousha That's almost the same as above code: just change `schedules` above to `abstract`, keep `controller` there (so it can be used on both `.view` and `.edit` states), add a `view` state definition similar to `edit` one above, then navigate to `schedules.view` inside `gotoView()`. What could be a problem?

Comment: @b0nyb0y how to do if the user surf directly into `/edit` and set `$scope.isEdit to true`?

Comment: @vzhen, for that, just check the URL/state (i.e. `$state.is('YOUR_STATE)`) and if the state is in `edit` mode, then set the `scope.isEdit = true`. Read here for more information: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_is

Answer (score 24):

REF: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statetransitiontoto-toparams--options

```
$state.transitionTo('yourState', params, {notify: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer because I think it's different enough from the accepted answer and may be useful to others:

I had two states, `begin` and `view`, with a bunch of optional parameters being synced with the URL for `view`, like so:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('begin',
        {
            url: '/',
            template: '<app-element></app-element>'
        })
    .state('view',
        {
            url: '/View?param1&param2&...&paramN',
            template: '<app-element></app-element>'
            params: {
               param1: {
                   value: null,
                   squash: true
               },
               ...
            }
        });
```

The link function for `<app-element>` would run any time I tried to sync the parameters using `$state.go`. Using `{notify: false, reload: false}` did not work for me. The link function still ran each time. I'm on 0.2 so `dynamic` isn't an available param option, either. I followed @b0nyb0y's suggestion and turned it into a parent/child relationship, which worked:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app',
        {
            url: '/',
            template: '<app-element></app-element>'
        })
    .state('app.view',
        {
            url: 'View?param1&param2&...&paramN',
            params: {
               param1: {
                   value: null,
                   squash: true
               },
               ...
            }
        });
```