# Prevent state reloading when changing states ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I understand this has been asked and answered in multiple posts but I have attempted the solutions and still can't quite get there yet.

I have a few components that I'm routing between with ui-router and one is a contact form which, if a user enters data to and moves to another route then back to the contact form the state is reloaded and the form contents gone.

I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581610/ui-router-change-state-without-rerender-reload-of-the-page) another way of doing this by having a parent state and child states but couldn't recreate this in my code.

Maybe there's a simpler solution by using [ui-router-extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/index.html#/) with the sticky option although I attempted this and could't get it working either. I'll post the code as it works now.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('personalPortfolio')
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

            $stateProvider
                .state('about', {
                    sticky: true,
                    url: '/about',
                    template: '<pg-about></pg-about>'
                })

                .state('development', {
                    sticky: true,
                    url: '/work',
                    template: '<pg-dev></pg-dev>'
                })

                .state('contact', {
                    sticky: true,
                    url: '/contact',
                    template: '<pg-contact></pg-contact>'
                });

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/about');
        }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service when You will store unsaved form data.

Comment: This would work although it's not that suitable as I also have another page that fetches some data and I only want that data to refresh on a full reload via the browser button.